# Is there a minimal implementation of Stellar Consensus Protocol besides stellar-core?

Tags: stellar-core, consensus, scp

I'm learning about consensus and I'd like to explore SCP in depth. However, the stellar-core implementation is difficult for a newcomer to grok. Is there a minimal SCP implementation elsewhere I can learn from, ideally in Rust or another high-level language?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are implementations either complete or in progress, but am not sure if any have been publicly released.  If you want to implement SCP, I strongly recommend starting with the [protocol specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-mazieres-dinrg-scp/) rather than the whitepaper.  Many of the people following the draft hang out on the [IRTF Decentralized Internet Infrastructure](https://www.irtf.org/mailman/listinfo/din) list, so that would be a good place to hear about or discuss implementations as well as to provide any feedback might have on the draft.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an alternate implementation of the SCP code. I’d recommend using the white paper as a starting point to take advantage of whatever language you’d pick to do it.